# UV Map doesn't show

Tags: uv

i'm still new to blender, i'm trying to uv unwrap the label for the bottle, i have mark seam and try to UV unwrap but the texture is missing i don't know why.

FYI the label is separate object from the bottle
i have check all forum relating to UV problem but could not find the same problem as mine
i'm using the blender 3

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have 2 materials, have you assigned the good material to your faces?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**Select your object in object mode, press "tab", press "A" to select all the geometry, select the material you want to assign and press the "assign" button**

Answer (score 0):

You have Image Editor opened, open UV Editor instead:

[image]

(or switch to UV Editing tab again)

Comment: No, it is two different editors, only one of them shows UV

Comment: Type Shift-F10.  Type it again.  It will toggle between what you think of as the "image editor" and the "UV editor".  They will have different menus along the top, and different tool choices.  But they are both instances of type IMAGE_EDITOR.  So in a way, I suppose, we're both right.

Comment: Doesn't matter. I haven't got the question